# How do you create a query to find number of entries between a range in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table right now that has a list of numbers (some repeating) that goes from 0 to 350.

Is it possible to write a query in Microsoft Access to return how many numbers in the set belong to a range?

For example, if the set of data is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, I want to create a query to return how many numbers below to the range between 3 and 6 (inclusive). In this example, it would return 4 since the numbers 3, 4, 5 and 6 are in this range.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used the 'COUNT' function in a query?

If not, use the query builder to select your number column TWICE from the table.

Add a criteria on your range of 3 to 6.

Set the query to 'Totals' see toolbar), then change your Criteria column to 'WHERE' (in the 'Totals' row),and change the other column to 'COUNT' (in the Totals row)

i.e

```
SELECT Count(Table1.ID) AS CountOfID
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.ID) Between 1 And 15));
```